# Why wireshark is not identifying my mongo packets?

Tags: mongodb, wireshark

I'm using *Wireshark* 3.0.0 (Git) to sniff *Mongo* packets.  I can see the packets in port `27017` but the protocol identifies them as `TCP` and not as `Mongo`.  After checking protocol preferences, Mongo port is set to `27017`.

Why doesn't wireshark detect the packages as `Mongo`?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Presumably because it goes over a regular TCP/IP socket per https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/

Comment: Can you post a capture file somewhere for analysis?

Comment: Check that the dissector is enabled in *Analyze --> Enabled Protocols...*.

Comment: @MikaS Mongo appers as enabled

Comment: Using _Analyze_ --> _Decode As..._ and changing TCP port 27017 and field _Current_ to **MONGO** makes the capture display them but it is not a permanent solution.